# Passive voice of the sentence

Tags: passive-voice, exam-questions

Why I can't go with option (d). Without 'by you' in the passive voice of the sentence , it is still having the same meaning without any ambiguity.Please explain.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Option D contains less information than the original sentence.  The original sentence implies that "you" should have brought it to my attention.  However, option D simply asks why "someone" didn't bring it to my attention.

There's nothing grammatically wrong with D.  It just isn't the most exact restatement of the original sentence.